# Can I complete a transaction some unspecified time after signature?

Tags: nft, opensea

I want to:

1. User signs and gives needed permissions
2. X time passes, an if statement in a code loop triggers
3. A specified NFT is listed for sale using open-sea API

Since this code will run through the night etc, I do not want to have the user have to sign the transaction immediately when the open-sea API is hit, instead, the user can sign way before the transaction occurs and let the transaction happen automatically at some time.

Any help is very much appreciated!